# BroadcastReceiver is not able to receive the Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to write a BroadcastReceiver to receive the application install action. But it failed, so I test if my receiver is well or not. So custom a intent, it also filed. below is my code. Please help me correct it.
    public class MyInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//    public MyInstallReceiver() {
//    }

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("receiver", "Intent Detected");
    if (intent.getAction (). equals ("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
        String packageName = intent.getDataString ();
        //System.out.println ("installed:" + packageName + "package name of the program");
        Log.d("receiver","installed:" + packageName + "package name of the program");
    }
}
}
```

custom  intent

```
public void installAPK(View v){
   startActivity(intent);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("receiver", "Intent sent");
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
       <receiver
        android:name=".MyInstallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <Intent-filter>
            <action   android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action   android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>

            <action android:name="com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT">
            </action>
            <Data   android:scheme = "package"   />
        </Intent-filter>
    </receiver>

enter code here
```

Comment: Did you declared your `BroadCastReceiver` in manifest file

Comment: What is your application package name and MyInstallReceiver package name

Comment: @bGorle The third party of code is the manifest. I am doubt if it is correct.

Comment: @MohdMufiz it is  package="ie.ucc.miao.fpj"

Comment: so receiver class is in default package?

Comment: yes it is in default package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about correct spelling in your manifest, but this code is definitely works very well:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyInstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Every application install/uninstall will trigger this receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Everythong looks good, expect a typo in your manifest. It should be `<intent-filter>` and not `<Intent-filter>`

Comment: hi, how to see if my receiver is running?

Comment: But failed :( ,no other way ?

Comment: Your data balise add the same typo. have you try to delete it ?